# Swift: Properly initialize and access my classes in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

This is from a Swift playground; I want to collect my 'Task' class instances in an array so each task's properties can be used in a tableview.  I'm searching for documentation but I don't see a discussion of how to properly initialize and access my classes in an array.

The last line of code gives an error that reads *AnyObject does not have member named deadline*.  It's the same whether I use a Swift Array of AnyObjects, or an empty NSMutableArray.  I tried various ways of casting it as an Integer, but it insists on this error.  Am I going about this the wrong way to store and then access data?  I'm javascript-brained, sometimes the similarity of the syntax leads me to delusions.

```
import UIKit

let todays_date = NSDate() // now
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let day_number = cal.ordinalityOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitYear, forDate: todays_date)

var tasks = [] as NSMutableArray

class Task {

    var title: String
    var interval: Int
    var dateActivated: Int
    var deadline: Int
    var flag_count: Int = 0
    var isActivated: Bool = false

    init(title: String, dateActivated: Int, interval: Int) {

        //initialized by selecting new
        self.title = title
        self.dateActivated = dateActivated
        self.interval = interval

        //calculated
        self.deadline = dateActivated + interval
    }

}

var task1 = Task(title: "Laundry", dateActivated: day_number, interval: 7)
var task2 = Task(title: "Dishes", dateActivated: day_number, interval: 7)

task1.deadline
task2.flag_count

tasks.addObject(task1)
tasks.addObject(task2)

tasks[0].deadline  //AnyObject does not have member named deadline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use foundation Arrays here, simply declare your array as `[Task]` (after declaring the `Task` class):

```
var tasks = [Task]()
```

Then use `append` instead of `addObject`:

```
tasks.append(task1)
tasks.append(task2)

tasks[0].deadline // 83
```